# Why does this function properly return data when not using the Sync variant of readFile?

Tags: node.js

When I call this code, which is an attempt to read the files in a directory into a filename: content array, it does not run the console.log(data) inside the readFiles() call. If I use readFile, it works as expected, but due to synchronous execution needs, this does not yield the data when used outside the call.

```
function readFiles(parameters) {
    var dirname = parameters.dirname;
    var onFileContent = parameters.onFileContent;
    var onError = parameters.onError;
    fs.readdir(dirname, (err, filenames)=>{
        if (err) {
            onError(err);
            return;
        }
        filenames.forEach(filename => {
             return fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(dirname, filename), 'utf-8', {stdio: [0, 1, 2]}, (err, content)=>{
                if (err) {
                    onError(err);
                    return;
                }
                onFileContent(filename, content);
            });
        });
    });
};


readFiles({
        dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../ping/'), onFileContent: (filename, content) => {
            data[filename] = content;
            //console.log(content);
            //global.data2 = data;
            console.log(data);
        }, onError: function (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }
    });
console.log(data);
```

When using the Sync variant, I am simply presented with {}, but async yields:

```
{ test_node: '{"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}' }
```

{ test_node: '{"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}',
  test_node_2: '{"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}' }

I understand that I need to use the Sync variant, but I am lost as to why this does not work as I expect it should.

Comment: When you call readFileSync, there is no callback parameter, you just get the result as return value.  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

Comment: How exactly should I implement this? I have tried addding in a return statement, but no dice.

Comment: readFileSync doesn't invoke a cb, therefore onFileContent is never called

Comment: I am completely unsure of how to change my code to not use the callback, do you have any advice on what I need to do?

Comment: I feel that if I used promises, I could use what I have, but I have never attempted to use them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a completely synchronous version of what I think you're looking for:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function readFiles(dir) {
    var files = {};

    fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .forEach(name => {
            if (fs.statSync(path.join(dir, name)).isDirectory()) return;

            files[name] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dir, name), 'utf8');
        });

    return files;
}

var files = readFiles('/some/folder');

console.log(files);
```

Comment: This is the solution, thank you so very much. This has helped me understand sync way better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

As you use readFileSync your code is somewhat easier to write, because you won't have to deal with the async-ness of it (you still have some async from readdir, but at least you have one less level of it to worry about).

This is what it could look like:

```
    function readFiles(parameters) {
      var dirname = parameters.dirname;
      var onFileContent = parameters.onFileContent;
      var onError = parameters.onError;
      fs.readdir(dirname, (err, filenames)=>{
        if (err) {
          onError(err);
          return;
        }
        filenames.forEach(filename => {
          var result;
          try {
            result = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(dirname, filename), 'utf-8', {stdio: [0, 1, 2]});
          } catch(err) {
            // we need to catch the errors synchronously too, so use a plain catch 
            // statement for this
            onError(err);
            return;
          }
          onFileContent(filename, result);
        });
      });
    }
```

I am not sure you need this `, {stdio: [0, 1, 2]}` either by the way (I am not familiar with that parameter and did not see it in the doc)

Comment: Hmmm, this is closer, but I am still not able to get the data into the data array.

Comment: So the way you are calling it, it's important to know that your `console.log` call right after the function call will not return anything, because it runs before the callback does.  You will only get the data inside of the callback.  If you are not dead set on needing the readdir to be async, you should look at Jeff McCloud answer, because it is a fully sync solution so it doesn't have any callback.